# A Simplicial Proof of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces representing cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Is the following sketch of a proof of "$K(G,n)$ represents $H^n(-;G)$" correct? I feel like it should be well-known, but my search didn't find anything.

Suppose $X$ is a CW complex. Singular cohomology is, by definition, $H^*(S_{Ab}(X),G)$ where $S_{Ab}(X)$ is the simplicial abelian group generated by the singular set of $X$. This is equivalent to $[S_{Ab}(X),G(n)]$ where $[-,-]$ denotes chain homotopy classes of maps and $G(n)$ is the chain complex with $G$ in the nth degree and 0 elsewhere.

Under the Dold-Kan correspondence $\Gamma: Ch^+ \rightarrow s\bf{Ab}$, this corresponds to the set $[\Gamma(S_{Ab}(X)),\Gamma(G(n))]$ (maps under simplicial homotopy equivalence) where presumably the thing on the left is weakly equivalent to $X$ after realization and the thing on the right is a $K(G,n)$ after realization. By the equivalence of $\operatorname{Ho}(Top)$ and $\operatorname{Ho}(SSet)$, geometric realization gives an isomorphism between the set of simplicial homotopy classes of maps and the homotopy classes of maps of its realization, so we are done.

Comment: The geometric realization of singular chains is much bigger than $X$; loosely speaking it's a homotopical generalization of the free abelian group on $X$. Fortunately this is exactly what you need to pass from "linear maps out of the free abelian group on $X$" to "maps out of $X$," but I don't know how easy it is to formalize the details here.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is the image of $\Gamma$ not a Kan complex in general then?

Comment: Oh, I see. The maps are in the simplical abelian group category not simplicial sets. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I also was incorrect that the cohomology was $[S_{Ab}(X),G(n)]$. I think this is actually just the cokernel of the boundary map of $S_{Ab}(X)$.

Comment: You are actually correct that chain homotopy classes of maps is cohomology. Try it for yourself.

Comment: Yes, I think I just hadn’t thought the entire proceeds completely through. I think if you write all the ideas correctly the proof works and is the exact same idea.